# Como fazer o relacionamento de um campo extra (pivot) em belongsToMany

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5

Atualmente tenho a seguinte situação:

- 1 Usuário pode pertencer a vários municípios
- Dentro desse relacionamento - `municipios_usuarios` - preciso salvar também quem fez esse relacionamento, ou seja, o `usuario_id`

---

```
public function municipios()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Projeto\DB\Municipio', 'municipios_usuarios')
        ->withPivot('criado_por_id', 'atualizado_por_id');
}
```

---

Como eu configuro **no Laravel 5.1** o relacionamento deste novo campo para que eu consiga acessar ele desta forma (ou de outra qualquer):

```
@foreach ($usuario->municipios => $municipios)
    {!! $municipio->pivot->criadoPor->nome !!}
@endforeach
```

A única maneira que eu consegui fazer isso foi fazendo um `join()` manualmente, porém eu gostaria de utilizar o **Eloquent**.

No mais, agradeço.

Se precisarem de mais informações me avisem.

Comment: Estou sem tempo pra montar a resposta, mas acredito que terá que fazer algo usando isso: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: @gmsantos vou verificar.

Comment: Nesse caso, o hasManyThrough não funciona.

Comment: Uma gambiarra que sempre faço é: Sem tenho uma tabela n:n com outros relacionamentos, eu crio um model da tabela do meio.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que como na tua tabela pivot você está apenas guardando o id do usuário, você terá que fazer um find com este id, ou o próprio join que você comentou.

De acordo com a documentação, ele não faz a associação do id obtido do pivot com o model.

A não ser que você defina um model para a tabela pivot e crie os relacionamentos dela com as outras. Assim você consegue este relacionamento que você quer.

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma biblioteca chamada `TriplePivot` que te permite relacionar três tabelas através de uma tabela pivot.

https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/Eloquent-triple-pivot

Answer (score -2):

```
public function municipios()
{

return $this->belongsToMany('Projeto\DB\Municipio', 'municipios_usuarios')

 ->withPivot(['criado_por_id', 'atualizado_por_id']);

}
```

tenta colocar os colchetes.